# How to improve difference-in-differences graph?

Tags: data-visualization, generalized-did

I want to visualise what basically is a difference in difference graph but in a better way. My first idea was two split violin plots and it looks good but is too complex for the reader.

[image]

Any ideas on what to use or how to make this look decent?

Here the data

| Group | Profit Round 2 | Profit Round 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Treatment | 198.4205 | 291.0428 |
| Control | 266.7899 | 311.5257 |

Comment: Please put your data in markdown: https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#

Comment: This seems like a very clear presentation of the data. What is it about the graph that you want to improve?

Comment: It seems too trivial to me in that way, perhaps there is an alternative to simple line charts that looks a little bit more "scientific" while conveying the message as clear

Comment: If a graph is able to convey the information without ambiguity, it is "scientific".

Answer (score 7):

I can tell that the treatment group starts out lower than the control group and, while the treatment group winds up lower than the control group, the treatment group has closed the gap. For difference-in-differences, this is exactly what I would want to see.

One possible improvement is to put standard errors on the four point estimates. Maybe more useful than that would be to plot the differences between control and treatment groups along with the standard errors of the differences.

If you just want to look fancy, bright colors tend to do the trick, though they will convey no additional information.

Comment: This sounds right to me.  One more possible suggestion is that showing the height from 0 is probably not very important in this context, so starting the y-axis just below the bottom of the error bar would allow the information to be presented in a larger format.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I finally did, perhaps this helps someone with a similar scenario:
[image]